# Prevent VBS from running multiple times at the same time

Tags: vbscript

I've added an entry (via the Registry) to Windows Explorer context-menu calling a VBS.

```
wscript "MyScript.vbs" "%1"
```

If multiple items are selected in Windows Explorer and the new context-menu command is used, I'd like the first instance of the script to complete before others start.

Is that possible?

Comment: How will you decide which process should continue next once the "active" process terminates?

Comment: That's part of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but I don't know exactly how you would do it in vbscript. vbscript is not one of my languages :(

Here is how I would attack this problem. Translate the code in article 1 into VBScript. I'd use the technique in 3 to import the methods mentioned in articles 2. Importing the method may take a little more research.

1. [Writing a Multithreaded Win32 Program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3x8b09y.aspx)
2. MSDN: [CreateMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx), [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx), [ReleaseMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. [How to call a DLL and its functions in VBS](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?447369-How-to-call-a-DLL-and-its-functions-in-VBS)

Comment: VBScript Is not my favorite language either. If there isn't a simple solution in VBS, I'd leave it as it is. *** Thanks for replying.